# How to detect the port to which a GPS device is connected in my program(C/C )

Tags: c++, c, gps, serial-port, nmea

I am writing a program to plot the route.
Is there a way to find out the GPS device connected port?
I can list out all available ports now. But would be nice to list the GPS device port.

Comment: Some more details would be appreciated: OS of host, make and model of GPS receiver. It might be possible to dig into the USB descriptors to find a COM port associated with a certain USB Vendor/Product ID.

Comment: @MSalters I don't believe it is possible to get the COM port associated with the USB device.  I can't find the StackOverflow post at the moment, but I researched this a couple years ago.  The USB device and the port itself are "disconnected" in a way.  In any case, those hardware IDs won't do you any good.  Many USB GPS units use off-the-shelf converters, such as the Prolific PL2302, inside to convert from RS232/RS485 to USB.  Therefore, it isn't possible to know the difference between the GPS unit, and any other converter dongle adapter.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this is to open each port, and listen a bit for NMEA data. The port attributes don't change based on the data sent through it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing standard in serial hardware that allows for easy identification (like deviceid's in usb). In the case of nmea protocol you will just have to open each port and see on which one the nmea data is coming in. Then close the ports you don't need.